# CMake FetchContent for just a git subdirectory

Tags: git, cmake

Given a project structure like:

```
-CMakeLists.txt
-lib
--CMakeLists.txt
--libA
---CMakeLists.txt
---libA.h
---libA.C
And so on...
```

I'm looking for a way to use `FetchContent` to just grab `libA`. I know using git commands this is (kind of) possible using sparse checkout, however is there a way to do this with `FetchContent`? I thought maybe using the `SOURCE_SUBDIR` option would help, but that seems to just be if the `CMakeLists.txt` for the whole project isn't in the root directory. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible. Is it important to clone only parts of the repository (e.g. because the whole repository is very big)? Otherwise, using `SOURCE_SUBDIR` to just  make `libA` available to your project sounds reasonable.

Comment: FetchContent is still relatively new. Perhaps suggest adding a sparse checkout functionality to the CMake developers. I know I've had similar concerns to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this will work with the combination of using `SOURCE_DIR`, `SUBBUILD_DIR`, `BINARY_DIR` and the aforementioned `SOURCE_SUBDIR`. Unfortunately, as we already knew, it still clones the entire repo.